# D7 - does drush rr ALSO clear cache?

Tags: 7, drush, caching

Someone just told me that in D7, drush rr and drush cc all do the same thing. I can’t find anything that explicitly states the difference, nor can I find anything that supports such a claim. Additionally, I’ve noticed there are some changes that seem to only show up with a drush cc all, particularly changes to code. Do drush rr and drush cc all actually implement the same functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/registry-rebuild/registry-rebuild

drush rr has the option:
`--no-cache-clear : Rebuild the registry only, do not clear caches.`

`drush rr` rebuild the registry + clear the caches.
`drush cc` clear the caches only.